# Getting all the checked checkboxes values at any given point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck at one point and unable to proceed further. I am trying to implement something like this below. The idea is to implement this,
If the checked checkbox length is greater than 2, then display the count else display the values of checkboxes. I am able to succeed in the checked checkboxes but unable to achieve when the user first checks the checkboxes and then unchecks. Please see the snippet. The output that I need at any point is to check if checkboxes length is greater than 2 and then do suitable actions. Can you please provide some light on this?

```js
checkboxLength = 0;
$('input[name="checkname[]"]').click(function() {
  checkboxval = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    checkboxLength++;
    if (checkboxLength > 2) {
      $('.selecteditems').html('<span>' + checkboxLength + ' Options selected</span>');
    } else {
      $('.selecteditems').append('<span>' + checkboxval + '</span>');
    }
  } else {
    checkboxLength = checkboxLength - 1;
    $('.selecteditems').html('<span>' + checkboxLength + ' Options selected</span>');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selecteditems"></div>
<div class="containerdiv">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Value 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 2">
  <label for="checkbox2">Value 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 3">
  <label for="checkbox3">Value 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 4">
  <label for="checkbox4">Value 4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 5">
  <label for="checkbox5">Value 5</label>
</div>
```

I am stuck at the else part. ie. that is if the checkboxes are unchecked and the length is less than or equal to 2.

Comment: The way you're counting checked checkboxes is faulty; at no point do you decrement that count, say when a checked checkbox is unchecked. Also clicking a checkbox does not always mean it went from unchecked to checked state, so the up-count too is faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can achieve your goal:

```
const $cn = $('input[name="checkname[]"]');
$cn.on('change', function() {
    const checkedLength = $cn.filter(':checked').length;
    console.log( checkedLength );
    const vals = $cn.filter(':checked').map((i,f) => f.value).get().join(',');
    const output = checkedLength > 2 ? `${checkedLength} options selected.` : vals;
    $('div.selecteditems').html( $('<span/>').text( output ) );
});
```

**LIVE DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
    const $cn = $('input[name="checkname[]"]');
    $cn.on('change', function() {
        const checkedLength = $cn.filter(':checked').length;
        console.log( checkedLength );
        const vals = $cn.filter(':checked').map((i,f) => f.value).get().join(',');
        const output = checkedLength > 2 ? `${checkedLength} options selected.` : vals;
        $('div.selecteditems').html( $('<span/>').text( output ) );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selecteditems"></div>
<div class="containerdiv">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Value 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 2">
  <label for="checkbox2">Value 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 3">
  <label for="checkbox3">Value 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 4">
  <label for="checkbox4">Value 4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 5">
  <label for="checkbox5">Value 5</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterKA. This works how I wanted. I forgot to mention one point which is - in the final output I would need separate spans. Here it is one span separated by commas. I tried adding a for loop with the checkLength and then placing output inside the loop, but dint work out. Ill figure out how to do it and get back. If you have any idea, please do suggest. Thanks

Comment: I have used for each loop and got my desired result. I am unable to upload the code in the comment box. How do I post my code?

Comment: Why are you using a loop? Do you really need to use a loop? Either you can add the updated code to the question as an update or, better still, ask a new question.

Why do you need separate `span` elements? Be aware that you would need to maintain the two elements; when you add text in one, you have to empty the other.

Comment: I will click on answer your own question and add the updated code. I need separate span elements because my output is such. What I have asked is a part of larger code. I was trying to implement something like multiselect but somehow did not like the UI of it so decided to do it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final code adding to the code which was given my @PeterKA

```js
const $cn = $('input[name="checkname[]"]');
$cn.on('change', function() {
  const checkedLength = $cn.filter(':checked').length;
  const vals = $cn.filter(':checked').map((i, f) => f.value).get();
  finalCheckedValue = '';
  $.each(vals, function(index, checkedValue) {
    finalCheckedValue += '<span>' + checkedValue + '</span>';
  });
  output = checkedLength > 2 ? `${checkedLength} options selected.` : finalCheckedValue;
  $('div.selecteditems').html(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selecteditems"></div>
<div class="containerdiv">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Value 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 2">
  <label for="checkbox2">Value 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 3">
  <label for="checkbox3">Value 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 4">
  <label for="checkbox4">Value 4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkname[]" value="Value 5">
  <label for="checkbox5">Value 5</label>
</div>
```

Please let me know if this approach is correct or do I have to do any modifications.